# Pandas fillna with list/array

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a convenient way of filling na values with (the first) values of an array or column?

Imagine the following DataFrame:

```
dfcolors = pd.DataFrame({'Colors': ['Blue', 'Red', np.nan, 'Green', np.nan, np.nan, 'Brown']})

  Colors
0   Blue
1    Red
2    NaN
3  Green
4    NaN
5    NaN
6  Brown
```

I want to fill the NaN values with values from another DataFrame, or array, so:

```
dfalt = pd.DataFrame({'Alt': ['Cyan', 'Pink']})

           Alt
0         Cyan
1         Pink
```

When there are more NaN's then fill values some NaN's should remain. And when there are more fill values, not all of them will be used. So we'll have to do some counting:

```
n_missing = len(dfcolors) - dfcolors.count().values[0]    
n_fill = min(n_missing, len(dfalt))
```

The number `n_fill` is the amount of values that can be filled.

Selecting the NaN values which can/should be filled can be done with:

```
dfcolors.Colors[pd.isnull(dfcolors.Colors)][:n_fill]

2    NaN
4    NaN
Name: Colors, dtype: object
```

Selecting the fill values

```
dfalt.Alt[:n_fill]

0    Cyan
1    Pink
Name: Alt, dtype: object
```

And them i'm stuck at something like:

```
dfcolors.Colors[pd.isnull(dfcolors.Colors)][:n_fill] = dfalt.Alt[:n_fill]
```

Which doesn't work... Any tips would be great.

This is the output that i want:

```
  Colors
0   Blue
1    Red
2   Cyan
3  Green
4   Pink
5    NaN
6  Brown
```

NaN values are filled from top to bottom, and the fill values are also selected from top to bottom if there are more fill values than NaN's

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: Good point, i edited the question a bit.

Comment: It's [returning view vs copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) (fancy indexing always returns a copy)... hmm

Comment: Yes I think thats a main issue, I have tried all kinds of things like adding `.values` or even wrapping it in a new DataFrame. No luck so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather awful, but iterating over the index of the nulls works:

```
In [11]: nulls = dfcolors[pd.isnull(dfcolors['Colors'])]

In [12]: for i, ni in enumerate(nulls.index[:len(dfalt)]):
             dfcolors['Colors'].loc[ni] = dfalt['Alt'].iloc[i]

In [13]: dfcolors
Out[13]:
  Colors
0   Blue
1    Red
2   Cyan
3  Green
4   Pink
5    NaN
6  Brown
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generator. That way you could write something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import np

dfcolors = pd.DataFrame({'Colors': ['Blue', 'Red', np.nan, 'Green', np.nan, np.nan, 'Brown']})
dfalt = pd.DataFrame({'Alt': ['Cyan', 'Pink']})

gen_alt = (alt for alt in dfalt.Alt)

for i, color in enumerate(dfcolors.Colors):
    if not pd.isnull(color): continue
    try:
        dfcolors.Colors[i] = gen_alt.next()
    except StopIteration:
        break
print(dfcolors)
#     Colors
# 0   Blue
# 1    Red
# 2   Cyan
# 3  Green
# 4   Pink
# 5    NaN
# 6  Brown
```